# add libraries external in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a question,

¿ What's the difference between **compile project(':library/materialtabs')** and **compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'** ?.

Because with the first option I have the following issue:

```
<it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabHost_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    app:primaryColor="@color/white"
    app:accentColor="#333333"
    app:hasIcons="true"
    app:iconColor="#ffffff" />
```

The following classes could not be instantiated:  it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost , 
but I use the other option  the issue is solved.

Answer (score 2):

```
compile project(':library/materialtabs')
```

**Code is part of your project.**

Means that you have an other "module" in your project. Which I think is also not spelled correctly as you can't have the "/" in the module-name.

In case the module is inside a folder can be referenced as `':library:materialtabs'` according to [this](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies) structure explanation.

---

```
compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
```

**Code is not part of your project, is just referenced from a remote resource.**

Means that you are going to download (this is done by gradle internally) the specific library from android `jcentral` or `mavenCentral` repository servers.

Comment: ok, but module name is materialtabs that is inside the library folder . the question is that when I modify the classes of materialtabs and I executed the application, the changes is not show.

Comment: I don't think that you understand my explanation... I edited the answer and hope that is more clear now. I guess you need the `compile project(':library:materialtabs')` reference but if it does not work then there is a problem either with the structure of your project or another gradle setting.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer... I decided not to use the library.